# ErgoDox Oryx bad font in Chromium browsers

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium, oryx

For all of my chromium based browsers, I'm getting a ***very*** bad font within Oryx for ErgoDox.  If you're not familiar with the tool, you can see [my keyboard layout here](https://configure.zsa.io/ergodox-ez/layouts/4OlQd/latest/0).

**Update:** I'm seeing in "Rendered Fonts" a strange font I don't recognize.  Now I'm trying to work out how this is even happening, and why it's all my chromium browsers.  See bottom photo below.

**Update 2:** The current theory is that my system is using the first "sans-serif" font it finds because of a syntax error in ErgoDox's CSS for the font-family; "Lato" should be enclosed in single quotes `'` and it is not.  This is causing my system to fall back to the first sans-serif font it finds, which is normally something more useful like "Arial", but is `pix PixelFJVerdana12pt` in my case.  I've installed both "Lato" and "LatoLatin" and it is still rendering this awful font.

**Update 3:** Uninstalling "pix PixelFJVerdana12pt" fixed the issue ?? Now I'm looking into that font to figure out what the heck that even is?  Now it renders Lato from the web?  I'm putting an updated screenshot at the bottom with it fixed.

**Here's what I've discovered and tried:**

- The site uses "Lato,sans-serif;" for all its fonts - loaded from [woff2](https://configure.zsa.io/fonts/lato-v17-latin-regular.woff2)/[woff](https://configure.zsa.io/fonts/lato-v17-latin-regular.woff2) files hosted on their site.
- This problem exists for all of my chromium browsers: Chrome, Brave, Vivaldi, Edge.
- The site loads just fine in chromium (Chrome) for a friend of mine.
- The site loads just fine for me on my mobile phone.
- Extensive searching online yields no reports of anyone else having this issue.
- The site displays fine in Firefox.
- I've installed Lato to my machine directly from Google Fonts.
- I've downloaded the woff2/woff files from ErgoDox and opened them using a woff viewer online; they display correctly there.
- Reloading the site with cache disabled does not work.
- There are no console, or network errors (in developer tools).
- The only extensions I have installed in this instance of chromium are: 1Password, Adobe Acrobat and Application Launcher for Drive (Google).
- I run Windows Defender and Malwarebytes Enterprise.

I highly suspect this issue is local to me, and not a more global issue.

Anyone else with this issue?  Any suggestions?

**Problem demonstration:**
[image: Strange font on ErgoDox Oryx in chromium]

**Weird rendered font:**
[image: Weird rendered font]

**After uninstalling "pix PixelFJVerdana12pt":**
[image: After uninstalling weird font]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to uninstall the "[pix PixelFJVerdana12pt](https://fonts2u.com/pix-pixelfjverdana12pt.font)" font.  I have no idea what is wrong with it, but it's now working as expected.

**Those of you who get your kicks out of IT troubleshooting and mysteries, this is a good one for you to try to figure out!  I'd still love to understand *why* this was happening - so strange.**

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but am avoiding uninstalling it try to figure out what's going on - I've seen the same thing happen on https://www.gamesatlas.com/ with "Open Sans", and even though Oryx uses "Inter" now, it's still happening there. Did you notice any other sites where it happened?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out and fixed it on my system - the font `pix PixelFJVerdana12pt`/`PixelFJVerdana12pt` by Flashjunior.ch has a TTF UniqueID of `0`, which must cause Windows's font handling to treat it differently. I changed this to the font's name in FontForge, and replaced it on my system - after a restart of Chrome, the fonts in Oryx and gameatlas.com seem to be how they were intended to look.

[image: Font Information for PixelFJVerdana12pt]